# Set up static ip for VM under NAT

Tags: routing, virtualization, nat, static-ip

I have a VM running Win srv 2016 on VMWare Player 12.5 behind NAT. What I would like to achieve is to set up a static ip for my VM.
I'm confused on where should I do it: in VMWare or directly on the OS?

Also I only found posts on how to achieve that in bridged or host-only mode, not NAT, why is it that?

Comment: Yes you will do it inside the OS. Setting a static IP in a VM is just like as you would do in your host machine

Comment: In the interface's property? Seems to work, thank you

Comment: You may want to move that to an answer @D.A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the IP of a VM can be done in the same way as in a host machine.

Bridged Mode allows you to get a new IP in the VM. NAT on the other hand utilises the network connection on your host machine to access the Internet.

More info: https://serverfault.com/a/490048/414514

In windows follow these steps:

1. Open Network and Sharing Center
2. Change Adapter Settings
3. Click on properties of your desired adapter
4. Internet Protocol 4 (or 6) Properties
5. Enter your static IP